# User profile synchronization

Tags: sharepoint, directory, profile

With SP 2010 and the user synchronization profile service, is it possible to combine multiple source of profile properties ?

By combining I mean property A is in one directory and property B is in another.
A real example is one of my customer which use AD to authenticate users and basic properties (phone, email, etc.), but has the user corporate position (grade, geographic office, etc.) in a legacy directory.
In SP profile, all these properties must be available (especially for targeting audience).

If it's not possible, what is the preferred approach ? Creating a custom profile source that encapsulate the combination ? (I imagine this quite painful and technically risky).

thx,
steve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You sure can.

http://www.kowalski.ms/2010/07/20/sharepoint-server-2010-supplementing-user-profile-imports-using-bcs/

There are other types of profile sources too.

As long as you can map the ident field from source 1 to source 2.